# Getting SIGABRT error on Codechef ? Its running on a testcase but giving Sigabrt error on remaining?

Tags: c++, c++14, dijkstra

### SIGABRT Error on Codechef

**Just wanna know where it is lacking.**

**I have tried many things but not getting the solution. Please help, Thanks in advance !!**

---

### Basic implementation of finding shortest path to every node using dijkstra

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define lli long long int
using namespace std;

lli t,n,k,x,m,i,a,b,j,c,s,g,h;

lli minimum(lli dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
lli min = INT_MAX,min_index;

for (lli v = 0; v<n; v++)
    if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
        min = dist[v],min_index = v;

return min_index;
}

lli answer(lli dist[],lli n)
{
for (lli i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%lli ",dist[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void sourabhDijk(const vector<vector<int> >& graph,long long int src)
{
lli dist[n];

bool sptSet[n];

for (lli i=0;i<n;i++)
    dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;

dist[src] = 0;

for (lli count=0; count<n-1;count++)
{
    lli u = minimum(dist, sptSet);

    sptSet[u] = true;

    for (lli v=0;v<n;v++)

        if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u]
                + graph[u][v]<dist[v])
            dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
}
answer(dist,n);
}


int main(){
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    
    cin>>n>>k>>x>>m>>s;
    vector<pair<lli,lli> > adj[n];
    vector<pair<lli,lli> >::iterator it;
    
    for(i=0;i<k;++i){
        for(j=i+1;j<k;++j){
        adj[i].push_back(make_pair(j,x));
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<m;++i){
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        adj[a-1].push_back(make_pair(b-1,c));
    }
    vector<vector<int> > v(n, vector<int>(n));
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(it = adj[i].begin();it!=adj[i].end();++it){
            g=it->first;
            h=it->second;
            v[i][g]=h;
            v[g][i]=h;
        }
    }
    sourabhDijk(v,s-1);
    v.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: That #define is really ugly. Please use typedef.

Comment: what is the problem with that #define  ?

Comment: Avoid macro processing as often as possible. typedef (or even using) is there to help you give names to types. There you have real language support, it's not text subsitution. So either do `typedef long long int lli` or `using lli = long long int;`

Comment: thanks for your reply.!